# An adjective to describe a woman that doesn't wear jewelry?

Tags: deverbal-adjectives

folks.
I want an attributive adjective or past/present participle adjective to describe a woman who doesn't wear jewelry?

Answer (score 1):

"Unadorned, plainly clad/dressed, unornamented, austere,unembellished," may be used to describe her.

"Plain, simple, sober" etc can also create the effect of her not using jewellery.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- *modest*
- *unfussy*
- *plain*

Answer (score -1):

gypsy-like - sounds like an obvious answer

ok, unadorned is closest in meaning to it

Comment: or gypsy-without-any-jewelry

Comment: I don't understand. Is there a stereotype that Gypsy women don't wear jewelry? If so, I've never heard of it before.

Comment: I agree with @sumelic -- the stereotypical view of a [Gypsy woman](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/48/40/88/484088f221a33208bd4f9854010b6ad4.jpg) is with jewelry.

Comment: Gypsy-like sounds all wrong, but **unadorned** is very good.

Answer (score -1):

How about?

- simple
- natural
- unembellished
- free spirited